Using Stokes' theorem to calculate the line integral

Using Stokes' theorem, compute the line integral:  $$\int_{(AmB)}
 \big(x^2 - yz\big) \, dx + \big(y^2 - xz\big) \, dy + \big(z^2 -
 xy\big) \, dz,$$ where $(AmB)$ is a segment of the helical curve
defined by $$x = a \cos \phi, \quad y = a \sin \phi, \quad z =
 \frac{h}{2\pi} \phi,$$ from point $A(a, 0, 0)$ to point $B(a, 0, h)$.

The answer is $\dfrac{h^3}{3}$. But I still don't know how to calculate this integral. Could someone help me?

??? Stokes Theorem requires a closed path.  A helix isn't closed.

@Paul may be include the segment AB then apply the theorem?

Yes, but you'd have to calculate the line integral along the segment separately.

If $\hat F=(x^2-yz)\hat i+(y^2-zx)\hat j+(z^2-xy)\hat k$, then the curl of this vector seems to be $0$.

All integrals in x,y go full circles, only the vertical integral  $\int_0^h z^2 dz$  yields the result independent of any parametrization.
